# Spring boot r2dbc transactional: which method to annotate

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc, r2dbc-postgresql

I am using spring-boot 2.4.2 with webflux to connect to a postgres database.
I observed a behavior while using `@Transactional` that I don't understand.

To showcase the behavior, I created an example application that attempts to add rows to two tables; table "a" and table "b". The insert to table "a" is expected to fail with a duplicate key violation. Given that transactional is used, I expect no rows to be added to table "b".

However, depending which method I annotate with `@Transactional` I get different results.

If I annotate the controller method, things work as expected and no row is added to table B.

```
    @PostMapping("/")
    @Transactional
    public Mono<Void> postEntities() {
        return demoService.doSomething();
    }
```

DemoService looks like this:

```
    public Mono<Void> doSomething() {
        return internal();
    }


    public Mono<Void> internal() {
        Mono<EntityA> clash = Mono.just(EntityA.builder().name("clash").build()).flatMap(repositoryA::save);
        Mono<EntityB> ok = Mono.just(EntityB.builder().name("ok").build()).flatMap(repositoryB::save);
        return ok.and(clash);
    }
```

If I move the `@Transactional` annotation from the controller to `doSomething()`, then the transactions still work as expected.
However, if I move the `@Transactional` annotation to `internal()`, then transactions don't work as expected. A row is added to table "b".

The full code of this example is here: https://github.com/alampada/pg-spring-r2dbc-transactional

I don't understand why moving the annotation to the `internal()` method causes issues to transaction handling. Could you please explain?

Comment: Have you seen any issues with the transaction management in case of spring webflux? Does this work without issues just like in spring web?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Spring reference documentation : [Using @Transactional](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/data-access.html#transaction-declarative-annotations)

> In proxy mode (which is the default), only external method calls
> coming in through the proxy are intercepted. This means that
> self-invocation (in effect, a method within the target object calling
> another method of the target object) does not lead to an actual
> transaction at runtime even if the invoked method is marked with
> @Transactional. Also, the proxy must be fully initialized to provide
> the expected behavior, so you should not rely on this feature in your
> initialization code (that is, @PostConstruct).

Here the call from doSomething() to internal() is a self-invocation.

Do note that Spring Framework’s declarative transaction support  is enabled via AOP proxies.

Spring reference documentation : [Understanding AOP Proxies](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies) will provide clarity on why self-invocation does not work on proxies. Do read through the section starting with
*The key thing to understand here is that the client code inside the main(..)*